# What about allowing file uploads up to 100MB through PHP?

Tags: php, upload

Is reasonable to allow file uploads up to 100MB through PHP ?

I'm currently allowing 64MB, but usually my customers only need 24MB. Can we improve that ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the php.ini directive [upload_max_filesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize). When you adjust this value you must also adjust [post_max_size](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) and [memory_limit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit). The general rule is that memory_limit > post_max_size > upload_max_filesize.

The problems with allowing larger file uploads are more memory (RAM) usage, greater disk space usage, and longer lived open connections to handle the uploads. You should ensure that all are in amble supply before allowing such a drastic increase in file upload size. Consider your visitors & if they are likely to be malicious (on the internet assume everyone is from 4chan /b/) then you should make certain that your solution is robust.

I have done 100MB file uploads for a audio/video upload site without problems, but the servers were monsters.

Comment: ok so I forgot to mention that the upload functionality is available only in the websites back-end for my custoemrs and not for any client. I guess that it's ok then.